# How to place 2 JButtons at the top of a JPanel (one centered, the other topright)?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I want to put 2 JButtons on my JPanel, one of them being centered and the other being in the top right corner of the JPanel. The JPanel is the same size as the JFrame that contains the JPanel. How can I do this using GridBagLayout and GridBagConstraints?

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
public MyPanel() {
    JButton btnGame1 = new JButton("Game 1");
    JButton btnExitFrame = new JButton("Exit");

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    add(btnGame1, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
    add(btnExitFrame, c);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

MCVE for camickr

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public MyPanel() {
    JButton btnGame1 = new JButton("Game 1");
    JButton btnExitFrame = new JButton("Exit");;

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel top = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT) );
    top.add( btnExitFrame );

    JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    center.add(btnGame1, new GridBagConstraints());

    add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

**FIXED SOL'N:**

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public MyPanel() {
        JButton btnGame1 = new JButton("Game 1");
        JButton btnExitFrame = new JButton("Exit");;

        int nOfCells = 3;
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());        
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < nOfCells; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < nOfCells; j++){
                c.gridx = i;
                c.gridy = j;               
                if(i == 1 && j == 0) {
                    c.anchor = c.PAGE_START;
                    add(btnGame1, c);
                    c.anchor = c.CENTER;
                }
                else if(i == 2 && j == 0) {
                    c.anchor = c.FIRST_LINE_END;
                    add(btnExitFrame, c);
                    c.anchor = c.CENTER;
                }
                else {
                    c.fill = c.BOTH;
                    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(frame.getWidth()/nOfCells, frame.getHeight()/nOfCells)), c);
                    c.fill = c.NONE;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image of the fixed text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b976J.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option only using GridBagLayout would be to add invisible Boxes as fillers to divide your JPanel into sections, and then substituting the Boxes in your preferred locations with your JButtons.

```
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.weightx = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<nOfCells; i++){
        for(int k=0; k<nOfCells; k++){

            c.gridx = i;
            c.gridy= k;
            this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT)), c);
        }
    }
```

GridBagLayout does not allow positions to be fixed in space, they depend on their position relative to the other components of the JFrame.

Comment: what should I define nOfCells as? (I have 2 buttons to put in the frame)

Comment: The nested for loops created a Grid on your Layout, with nOfCells boxes in each direction. The number you choose depends on how you want your Frame to look, just imagine dividing your JFrame in nOfCells^2 boxes of a defined size and see what number might be more aesthetic.

Comment: Okay I took a stab at making a 3 by 3 and it turned out funky. Would you be able to paste a code block below your original response that shows how you'd edit the MyPanel constructor to get the "Game 1" button to be in the top center of the JFrame and "Exit" in the top right?

Comment: Okay I messed with a little more over the past 2 weeks and I think I finally get the hang of it from your suggestion. I got the buttons to place properly.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the `BorderLayout` of the frame and use nested panels.

```
JPanel top = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(set right alignment) ); // read FlowLayout API
top.add( topRightButton );

JPanel center = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
center.add(centerButton, new GridBagConstraints());

frame.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Edit:

Don't use static variables like that. If you think you need to use a static variable then you have a design issue.

Since you are adding the MyPanel class directly to the frame, you need the following changes to effectively make your MyPanel class the container that uses the `BorderLayout`:

```
//setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

...

//frame.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
//frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I suggest you can also read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). The demo code there will show another way to add components directly to the frame.

Your current code (plus the above changes I suggested) is probably the better approach. But you should understand both approaches to better understand how layout managers work.

Comment: Um when I do this the Exit button shows in the right place but the Game 1 button is gone. (I assume "set right alignment" is `FlowLayout.RIGHT`).

Comment: @takanuva15, If the game button doesn't show you did something wrong. Post your [mcve] using this approach that's demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I put it up on the question

Comment: @takanuva15, I said you need to take advantage of the BorderLayout of the frame. You are not doing this. You are adding the MyPanel class to the frame. This is replacing the "center" panel. Since you are not adding components to the MyPanel class there is nothing to see in the CENTER of the frame. See edit.

Comment: Cool that's much better! However, I would like the Game1 button to be at the top center of the JFrame, not the middle center. How would I fix that? (See my edits to the question)

Comment: @takanuva15, I really can't follow your exact requirement. I've given you the concept of how to use multiple panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired layout. I've also given you a link to the tutorial. So read the tutorial. Read up on all the different layout managers. Mix and match nested panels and layout managers to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: If you want everything on one line, then I would suggest a `BoxLayout` and you can add "horizontal glue" before and after the game button.